# tableau how to connect duckdb

Tags: jdbc, tableau-api, tableau-desktop, duckdb

I download the duckdb jdbc driver and copy it to the install directory: C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers\duckdb_jdbc-0.2.9.jar
then I start the tableau , and choose the others jdbc drivers to connect,
[set the configuration like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOrZ3.png)
try to connect to duckdb
[the fail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9PQX.png)
any other configuration left? I already checkout the offical documents and found nothing related to this.

by the way, I can connect successfully using the Jetbrains Datagrip IDE after set the proper className and the same connection url?

the duckdb database behave like sqlite but for analytical workload. https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/data_viewers/tableau